# Indexes of first occurrences of zeroes in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list like this,

```
import numpy as np
myList = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]
```

I can find the index of non zero occurrence like below.

```
I = np.nonzero(myList)
for i in I:
  print(i)
```

Can I find the `index of first occurrence` of zeros? something like below,

```
[0, 5, 7, 11]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since NumPy tagged, here are two ways -

```
In [44]: m = np.r_[False,np.equal(myList,0)]

In [45]: np.flatnonzero(m[:-1]<m[1:])
Out[45]: array([ 0,  5,  7, 11])
```

If the input is an array, becomes a bit easier to get the equivalent mask `m` -

```
a = np.array(myList)
m = np.r_[False,a==0]
```

Another way with `np.diff` for a one-liner -

```
In [46]: np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0,np.equal(myList,0)])==1)
Out[46]: array([ 0,  5,  7, 11])
```

Easier again with array input `a` -

```
In [52]: np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0,a==0])==1)
Out[52]: array([ 0,  5,  7, 11])
```

Answer (score 2):

With python

```
i = True
r = []
l = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]
for a in range(len(l)):
    if l[a] == 0:
        if i:
            r.append(a)
            i = False
    else:
        i = True
print(r)
```

Prints

```
[0, 5, 7, 11]
```